# How to get location every 10 sec using flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I am very new to flutter. I have to make an app that send the device location every 10 seconds, even if app is minimised and gets killed by the user.
After that data i have to make a socket connection and a http post if(socket fails).

The app should must work with both Android and IOS.
Is it possible to do in flutter?

Comment: Nothing is impossible. So what have you tried so far? your question is unanswerable. you are asking a whole function?

Comment: You just need to start working on it. first run in your terminal `flutter create your_app_name`

Comment: @pmatatias yes i have tried doing it with workmanger and geolocator but workmanager fails when app is terminated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

background locator 2:
https://pub.dev/packages/background_locator_2
Android works. The problem is that the time values are slightly random
The value is delivered well within 10 seconds when the app is closed. However, if the app is turned off for a long time, due to the nature of Android, it is forcibly switched to sleep mode, so the return value is slightly random.

iPhone works fine

background_geolocation works well instead of being paid
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_geolocation

Answer (score 0):

You would subscribe to a Location-Stream, for example using this package:

https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator

Using a period-timer you would push the location to a server-side service.
This should work in Fore- and Background-state.

But measuring location for "terminated" apps is a lot more difficult.
You need to install some kind of persistent background service.

This plugin may give you some answers:

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_geolocation